# How do I insert multiple rows of JSON object data in mySQL using PHP PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, pdo

I making PHP API to insert multiple rows of **JSON** object data. My **JSON data format** is like this:

*(I receive this below format in console log for console.log(this.state.cartItems[]).*  in REACT)

```
0: {SparePartID: "34", qty: 1, Price: "500", OrderID: "14"}
1: {SparePartID: "35", qty: 1, Price: "250", OrderID: "14"}
2: {SparePartID: "36", qty: 1, Price: "430", OrderID: "14"}
```

My PHP Api code is below:

---> **part_order_details.php**

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost/Auth/");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With");

include_once '../config/database.php';
include_once '../objects/order.php';


$database = new Database();
$db = $database->getConnection();


$order = new Order($db);

$a = file_get_contents("php://input");
$data = json_decode($a, true);

if($order->orderDetails($data)){

    http_response_code(200);
    echo json_encode(array(
        "message" => "All rows of Order Details are inserted.",

    ));
}
else{

    http_response_code(400);
    echo json_encode(array("message" => "Sorry! Error while inserting rows of order details"));
}
```

and -----> **order.php** is:

```
class Order{

    private $conn;

    public $SparePartID;
    public $OrderID;
    public $Price;
    public $Quantity;

    public function __construct($db){
        $this->conn = $db;
    }


    function orderDetails($arr)
    {
       $query=  "INSERT INTO sparepartorderdetails (SparePartID, OrderID, Quantity, Price) VALUES
      (:SparePartID, :OrderID, :qty, :Price) ";
      
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);

        foreach($arr as $item)
        {
            $stmt->bindValue(':SparePartID', $item[0]);
            $stmt->bindValue(':qty', $item[1]);
            $stmt->bindValue(':Price', $item[2]);
            $stmt->bindValue(':OrderID', $item[3]);

          if($stmt->execute()){
            return true;
        }
        else{
           $arr = $stmt->errorInfo();
            print_r($arr);
        }
        }
    }
}
```

For now, Im trying to test PHP API with **POSTMAN**.
so Im sending this data in Postman body for **POST** request:

```
{
"0":
{"SparePartID": "34",
"qty": "1",
"Price": "500",
"OrderID": "14"},

"1":
{"SparePartID": "35",
"qty": "1",
"Price": "250",
"OrderID": "14"}

}
```

But the POSTMAN shows **ERROR** Status: *400 Bad Request* with msg:
{
"message": **"Sorry! Error while inserting rows of order details"**
}

I searched this problem a lot, but no solution.
Am I missing something or using wrong way to insert multiple JSON rows?

Comment: Can you show the actual raw data that is posted?  Because what you're showing up at the top there is not valid JSON.

Comment: @PatrickQ The raw data Im posting in POSTMAN is the one at the very end of my question.  {
"0":
{"SparePartID": "34",
"qty": "1",
"Price": "500",
"OrderID": "14"},

"1":
{"SparePartID": "35",
"qty": "1",
"Price": "250",
"OrderID": "14"}

}

Comment: Okay, so first thing, if you are wanting to insert multiple records in one request, do not `return` within your loop.  Perhaps keep track of which records inserted successfully and which didn't, and then report the results at the end.  In terms of your execute seemingly returning false, look into [PDO error handling](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php) to help you spot the exact issue.

Comment: You need to get a more useless error from the db class when inserting.

Comment: @RaymondNijland I didn't understand what u mean. Would u plz explain how to solve this issue? Thanks

Comment: @RaymondNijland Perhaps you mean a more useFUL error  :)

Comment: @PatrickQ I EDITED the code of order.php and added **$this->conn->errorInfo()** but shows no error info

Comment: @YellowMinion `errorInfo()` doesn't _output_ anything. Please make sure you are reading the documentation carefully.

Comment: @PatrickQ Code edited. Now it outputs ther error **"NOTICE:  Undefined offset: 0  Undefined offset: 2  Undefined offset: 3  Undefined offset: 4"**

Comment: @YellowMinion That's because your inner arrays are associative arrays (key-indexed), not numerically-indexed arrays.

Comment: As a total aside: use `require_once` instead of `include_once`.

Comment: You need to use json_decode without the associate argument.  You're trying to use $item[0] but there is no 0 index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem mainly lies on this line:

`$data = json_decode($a, true);`

in connection with the binding of data:

```
$stmt->bindValue(':SparePartID', $item[0]);
$stmt->bindValue(':qty', $item[1]);
$stmt->bindValue(':Price', $item[2]);
$stmt->bindValue(':OrderID', $item[3]);
```

When you `json_decode` with the `true` argument for associative, your resulting data will be an array of arrays whose keys are strings, not integers.  So you would need to change how you access each property from integer indexes to string indexes.  You could change the bindValue occurrences to something like this:

```
$stmt->bindValue(':SparePartID', $item['SparePartID']);
$stmt->bindValue(':qty', $item['qty']);
$stmt->bindValue(':Price', $item['Price']);
$stmt->bindValue(':OrderID', $item['OrderID']);
```

An alternative to the above solution would be to change how you use `json_decode`.  Remove the `true` and update your `bindValue` occurrences to use object property access (since now the data will be decoded into Objects instead of Arrays):

`$data = json_decode($a);`

```
$stmt->bindValue(':SparePartID', $item->SparePartID);
$stmt->bindValue(':qty', $item->qty);
$stmt->bindValue(':Price', $item->Price);
$stmt->bindValue(':OrderID', $item->OrderID);
```

A final note on your `$stmt->execute` use is that after the first loop iteration your function will `return true` (if success).  It won't ever get to finish the remaining items to insert.  You should remove the early `return` statement and find a better way to return a success/failure indicator.